# Creating a list of elements of .xlsx file single column

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsx

I'm stacking with a problem: I'm trying to create a list of floats in a single column of my .xlsx file. And I have this `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

```
x = []

wb=load_workbook('sample_data1(dynamics).xlsx')
ws = wb.active
columnX = ws['L']

for i in range(len(columnX)): 
    if columnX[i+1].value != '-': %Just because in some cells of this column I have '-'
        x.append(float(columnX[i+1].value))
```

When I try another version of code:

```
x = []

wb=load_workbook('sample_data1(dynamics).xlsx')
ws = wb.active
columnX = ws['L']

for i in range(len(columnX)): 
    if columnX[i].value != '-' or columnX[i].value != 'Point of Regard Right X [px]': %Just because first cell contain 'Point of Regard Right X [px]'
        x.append(float(columnX[i].value))
```

I have this error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Point of Regard Right X [px]`.

So, can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas (with xlrd) usually does the trick for me:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('sample_data1(dynamics).xlsx')
col = 'REQUIRED COL'
col_values_list = list(df[col])
```

pandas will handle the conversion of the values to float.

Comment: What do u mean by REQUIRED COL? Just L? 
Then, I have this 'KeyError: 'L''

Comment: that's the column name. you can check the "recognized" columns using "print(df.columns)". I can't say for sure why you get this error without seeing you xlsx file